# How to remove cavity from edge masks?

Tags: node-editor, masking

How to remove cavity from edge masks on node editor? The obvious way would be to subtract a cavity mask from the edge mask, but that does not work, the mask is simply diminished on the cavity, instead of disappearing, even after subtracting several times.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Managed to do it by using inverted pointiness of Geometry node instead of Ambient Occlusion node.

[image]

Comment: @Gorgious There are many ways to generate edges, so it does not really matter what is inside the group in this case. The relevant node to solve the question's problem is the Geometry one, which erases edge masking on cavities.

Comment: Sure, fair game.